# EWS API throws exception from the method EmailMessage.Bind()

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams

We have been using the EWS API to access the MS Teams messages and it was working great in production until we get this issue for one of the client.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Array cannot be null. Parameter name: bytes
at System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(String chars, Int32 charIndex, Int32 
charCount, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GenerateRequestLine(Int32 headersSize)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SerializeHeaders() 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
at     
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.
WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
at 
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(
IEwsHttpWebRequest request) 
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(
IEwsHttpWebRequest& request) 
at         Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute() 
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalBindToItems(
IEnumerable`1 itemIds, PropertySet propertySet, String anchorMailbox, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling) 

at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToItem(ItemId itemId, PropertySet propertySet) 
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToItem[TItem](ItemId itemId, PropertySet propertySet) 
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.Bind(ExchangeService service, ItemId id, PropertySet propertySet)
```

Code snippets:

```
 ChangeCollection<ItemChange> changeCollection=null;
 List<Item> syncedItems = null;

 changeCollection = _exchangeService.SyncFolderItems(exchangeFolder.Id,
                new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.ItemClass), null,
                _syncBatchSize,
                SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems,
                currentSyncState);

 syncedItems = changeCollection.Where(d => d.ChangeType == ChangeType.Create || d.ChangeType == ChangeType.Update)
                        .Select(c => c.Item).ToList();

foreach (var item in syncedItems)
{
  if (!item.ItemClass.Equals("IPM.SkypeTeams.Message"))
      continue;

  EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(_exchangeService, item.Id.UniqueId,
                    new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Attachments,
         ItemSchema.TextBody));
   //...code to store message
 }
```

issue#1
For some message id, the method EmailMessage.Bind() throws the above exception.
We tried to replicate this issue at our Dev machines but it did not replicate on our Dev MS Teams.

issue#2
For some other message, we saw that this method just return null for the message.

We are trying to find out the actual cause for these two issues. For these, we tried to create different type of possible message in MS teams but still not able to replicate these.

The item class for these MS teams message is "IPM.SkypeTeams.Message".

Could anybody shed some lights on this?

Comment: 1) is the user a guest user? and 2) where is the user's Exchange mailbox?

Comment: Thank you @BillBliss-MSFT for the response.
We are skipping for guest user.

For messages/conversation access, we ask clients to enter Admin Username and Password that should have access all user's mailboxes. The entered user should have ApplicationImpersonation role in Exchange which allows reading all user's mailboxes.

Comment: In the stacktrace it looks like its a problem with the EWS response (eg it failing to parse the response it got). It looks like your requesting the TextBody so maybe your getting unexpected content there. You probably need to look at some network captures with Fiddler against a Mailbox where you know the problem exists. It would be hard to reproduce in a dev environment unless you can export/import the contents of that folder from a Mailbox where you know the problem is occurring.(if its content related you should just be able to reproduce it with a normal FindItem on the folder contents).

Comment: Thank you @GlenScales for the response. This is happening in the production and we do not have access to it to run fiddler or anything. The team is trying to get credential of that exchange mail box but not sure if we can get it.
From the logs, we knew that for this client, the same exception happens at this message again and again and could not move forward to read next messages after this.
So, we are planning to catch this exception, log the failed message id and move to next message id.